# Проблема со сохранением изменений в текстовый файл

Tags: c++, массивы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Было задание, условие которого отредактировать текст, данный в текстовом документе, отредактированный текст сохранить в этот же документ. Так вот, может это глупый вопрос, но как сохранить отредактированный текст в текстовый документ?)

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string RedactText(string s)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
        if (s[j] == '-' && s[j + 1] == '-')
        {
            s.replace(j, 2, " - ");
        }
        if (s[j] == ' ')
        {
            while (s[j + 1] == ' ') s.erase(j + 1, 1);
        }
        if (s[j] == '.' && s[j + 1] != ' ')
        {
            s.replace(j, 1, ". ");
        }
        else if (s[j] == ',' && s[j + 1] != ' ')
        {
            s.replace(j, 1, ", ");
        }
        else if (s[j] == ':' && s[j + 1] != ' ')
        {
            s.replace(j, 1, ": ");
        }
    }
    if (s[0] == ' ') s.erase(0, 1);
    if (s[s.length() - 1] == ' ') s.erase(s.length() - 1, 1);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    fstream F("C:\\Это папка\\Бейсбол.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    string a;
    while (getline(F, a))
    {
        a = RedactText(a);
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    F.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

Уже что только не пробовал, и ifstream + ofstream и просто fstream вводил, в лучшем случае текст просто не сохранялся. Что-то я явно делаю не так...

Comment: Вам нужно очистить файл после чтения?

Comment: Ну, можно открыть файл, отобразить его на память с возможностью изменения (записи) и изменять как обычный массив :-). А если с этим разбираться лень, то, например, открываете второй файл на запись, пишете туда первый файл с нужными изменениями, как все удачно записали - закрываете оба, первый удаляете, второй переименовываете. Если чего, это из соображений чтоб ничего не пропало.

Comment: Открываете в режиме RW без флага добавления в конец, дампите файл в память, редактируйте, пишите обратно. профит

Comment: Not Bjarne Stroustrup, да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// RedactText code

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    fstream F("C:\\Это папка\\Бейсбол.txt", ios_base::in);
    // Здесь нужна проверка на успешность открытия файла
    string a;
    vector<string> fileStrings;
    while (getline(F, a))
    {
        fileStrings.push_back(RedactText(a));
    }

    F.close();

    F.open("C:\\Это папка\\Бейсбол.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
    copy(fileStrings.begin(), fileStrings.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(F, "\n"));
    F.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```